# Изменение класса CSS с помощью PHP. Проблема в Google Chrome

Tags: php, css, классы, google-chrome

Есть картинка, по клику на которую элемент добавляется в избранное пользователя. При клике меняем переменную FalgFav, и класс на "active DeleteFavorite", либо на "addFavorite".

```
<span class="like <?php if($flagFav) echo "active DeleteFavorite"; else echo "addFavorite"; ?>"></span>
```

В FireFox работает как предполагалось, в Google Chrome - нет. В хроме при нажатии на картинку, класс addFavorite меняется на "addFavorite active DeleteFavorite",

```
<span class="like addFavorite active DeleteFavorite"></span>
```

а должен на "active DeleteFavorite". В итоге, после этого нельзя поменять класс обратно на addFavorite. Почему так происходит, если flagFav может принимать только два значения: True или False?

Comment: попробуйте `<span class="like <?php=($flagFav ? 'active DeleteFavorite' :  'addFavorite') ?>"></span>`

Comment: замена на тернарный оператор не помогает..  <span class="like <?php echo ($flagFav) ? 'active DeleteFavorite' : 'addFavorite'; ?>"></span> - остается та же проблема.

Comment: _"При клике меняем переменную"_ страница при этом полностью перезагружается?

Comment: нет. Страница не перегружается полностью. Если после клика обновляем страницу, то условие if else работает как нужно.

Comment: Тогда что происходит при клике на картинку? Javascript? Можно увидеть код?

Comment: да, javascript.

Comment: Тогда с чего вы взяли, что php-код выполнится в javascript? Браузеры не умеют в пхп

Comment: этот код писал не я :/ я не знаю честно как он работает в деталях. при клике мы меняем данные в базе данных, потом это проверяется на php и меняет переменную. Иногда (!) работает, иногда нет. Даже без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: значит (видимо) ищите совсем не там. это явно не тот код